# media query not working in chrome and device but working on firefox

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, responsive-design

I am working with mobile menu, in mobile device i need mobile menu. For that i did this

```
<style type="text/css">
.navbar-mini-menu a {
   color: #fff !important;
   cursor: pointer;
   display: block;
   padding: 1rem 1.5rem;
   text-decoration: none;
   transition: background-color .16s ease-in;
}

.navbar-mini-menu a:hover {  background-color: #CD5C5C; }
.navbar-mini-menu {  background-color: #000;  display: none; }
.navbar-mini-menu .menu-select {  color: #fff;  padding: 0.4rem 1.5rem; }

.navbar-mini-menu .menu-select .btn-select {
    background: url("http://test.coachfxlive.com/images/mobile-icon.png") no-repeat;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    right: 10px;
    top: 10px;
}

.navbar-mini-menu .mini-menu-options {  display: block; }
.navbar-mini-menu .mini-menu-options li {  display: block; }
.navbar-mini-menu .mini-menu-options li .submenu {  display: none; }
.navbar-mini-menu .mini-menu-options li:focus {  outline: 0; }
.navbar-mini-menu .mini-menu-options li:focus > .submenu {
     display: block;
     -webkit-animation-name: showSubMenu;
     -webkit-animation-duration: .4s;
 }

.navbar-mini-menu .mini-menu-options li a {  display: block;  padding: 1rem 1.5rem; 
}


.header {
   background-color: #000;
   height: auto;
   left: 0;
   min-height: 43px;
   padding: 6px 0;
   position: fixed;
   top: 0;
   width: 100%;
   z-index: 1000
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
 .header {  margin: 0;  }
 .header {  display: none;  }
 .navbar-mini-menu {   display: block; }
 .navbar-mini-menu .mini-menu-options {  display: none;  }
 .topgap{   display: none; }
}
</style>

<div class="header">menu</div>
<div class="navbar-mini-menu">mobile menu</div>
```

So, it should show mobile menu in mobile, but it not affecting in chrome and mobile also. Although same thing working in my other page.

Live workin link http://test.coachfxlive.com/user

Live not working link http://test.coachfxlive.com/shop

Comment: Please share the detail html markup. Its cause issue may be because your style .navbar-mini-menu .mini-menu-options {  display: none;  } OR set demo code at jsfiddle.net

Comment: @Prasad ok i updated style for both div here. should i update anything else?

Comment: I was saying about html markup and It would be great if you add your demo code to [link](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: i made fiddle here [http://jsfiddle.net/dkyw1sf0/](http://jsfiddle.net/dkyw1sf0/). but its working in fiddle. but not with my code.

Comment: @Prasad i have live link of my code. [http://test.coachfxlive.com/store](http://test.coachfxlive.com/store) (not working link) and [http://test.coachfxlive.com/user](http://test.coachfxlive.com/user) (working link).

Comment: Checking on chrome, Both links menu are working fine for me.

Comment: @Prasad if you resize chrome then it will work, but if you check in chrome with iphone4 view then it will not work, even link not working in mobile. so you have any idea why its not working in mobile?

Comment: Yeah, you have tons of issues. If it was just a couple I would debug for ya but wow, you are going to need a bootstrap wizard who has a little extra time on their hands, I can tell you that your header is not the issue, if you manually reduce the size of your header it does not make the total size smaller ?

Comment: no it does not. i think so. so what is the solution for that

Comment: If I had to guess, you are probably not linking a style sheet or javascript file correctly in your `<head>`

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith i already likned javascript and css in <head>

Comment: @SanketSorathiya I can see that, that is why I said "correctly" or possibly have a duplicate that is overriding another.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84550/discussion-between-sanket-sorathiya-and-adam-buchanan-smith).

Answer (score 0):

Here is my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/3fhgfbb2/1/ , all I added was some color to show that media query is working and changed the `max-width:` to 500px so it works better with the fiddle.

here is the css

```
.header{width: 100%; height: 100px; background-color: blue; text-align: center;color: white;}
.navbar-mini-menu{
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100px; 
    background-color: red; 
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    display: none;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
 .header {  margin: 0;  }
 .header {  display: none;  }
 .navbar-mini-menu {   display: block; }
 .navbar-mini-menu .mini-menu-options {  display: none;  }
 .topgap{   display: none; }
}
```

Comment: i updated my question. and your code is working i know but i dont know why it not working in my page. even same code is working for me in other page

Answer (score 0):

Issue is not with media query or bootstrap, It because of this meta tag

```
<meta name="viewport" content="maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=yes,width=1024" >
```

I replaced it with this one, and it working great.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
```